# How can i build a hierarchical JTable?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm trying in my code to build a hierarchical JTable. I'm using the designer of NetBeans.

I want to make the table Hierarchical.

I mean, that user can choose to add a row that will be in lower hierarchy then the upper row.

(This table represents a conditions table.According to the conditions that user provided me, I will build for him an Sql Statement).

Answer (score 4):

maybe you are looking for [JTreeTable](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/), in Netbeans farms is there [Outline](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4447#4447), [code depots by one Swing Guru here](http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/), excelent workaround into [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/), and some [Commercial products](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm)

Comment: I'll second the recommendation for the Jide Software (http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm) products.  I used them at my previous position, and they're simply terrific.

Comment: +1 I'm still happy with [`Outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4447#4447).

Comment: @trashgod agreed but required more than basic knowledges about Java & Swing, maybe SwingX or Grids are suits for NewBee :-)